# Wit.ai How to add dynamic Quick Replies

Tags: node.js, facebook, facebook-messenger, wit.ai, facebook-messenger-bot

Here is the sentence from the Wit.ai doc : [https://wit.ai/docs/recipes#categorize-the-user-intent](https://wit.ai/docs/recipes#categorize-the-user-intent<br/)

How to add dynamic Quick Replies

> If you want to programmically create Quick Replies, you will need to
>   use a Bot Executes to trigger a function on your side that will create
>   these Quick Replies.

Ok, I can do that easily !

> You can then store them in your context. In the
>    send function on your side, if you have them in the context you will
>   send them with the bot’s answer.

Can someone translate this last sentence for me because I don't understand what I shroud do. I want to add dynamic Quick Replies in my Node.js bot With Wit.ai
Thank you

Answer (score 5):

I'm doing something like this for my bots using Wit.ai for Facebook Messenger.

In my action I store my dynamic quick replies in context:

```
myAction({ context, text, entities }) {
  context.quick_replies = [
    { 
      title: 'Option A',
      content_type: 'text',
      payload: 'empty'
    },
    { 
      title: 'Option B',
      content_type: 'text',
      payload: 'empty'
    },
  ]
}
```

And then in `send()` I attach any quick replies to my text message:

```
send(req, res) {
  await textMessage(messenger_id, res.text, req.context.quick_replies)
}
```

Where `textMessage()` looks something like this:

```
export async function textMessage(recipientId, text, quick_replies = null) {
  const messageData = {
    recipient: { id: recipientId },
    message: {
      quick_replies: quick_replies,
      text: text
    }
  }

  await request({
    url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages',
    qs: { access_token: FB_PAGE_TOKEN },
    method: 'POST',
    json: messageData
  })
}
```

Basically, I create and attach the quick replies on my own.

If you have static quick replies in Wit.ai, then you will get them in `send()` in this format: `res.quickreplies = ['Yes', 'No']` and then you can format and attach these options.